# How can parse my json result

Tags: java, android, json

I am working in android. I want to parse my json data.

This is my json data:-

{

"response":{

```
  "groups":[

     {

        "type":"nearby",
        "name":"Nearby",
        "items":[
           {
              "id":"4ed0c8f48231b9ef88fe5f09",
              "name":"Banayan Tree School",
              "contact":{

              },
              "location":{
                 "lat":26.857954980225713,
                 "lng":75.76602927296061,
                 "distance":510
              },
              "categories":[
                 {
                    "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1a8941735",
                    "name":"General College & University",
                    "pluralName":"General Colleges & Universities",
                    "shortName":"Other - Education",
                    "icon":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/categories\/education\/default.png",
                    "parents":[
                       "Colleges & Universities"
                    ],
                    "primary":true
                 }
              ],
              "verified":false,
              "stats":{
                 "checkinsCount":5,
                 "usersCount":4,
                 "tipCount":0
              },
              "hereNow":{
                 "count":0
              }
           }

        ]
     }
  ]
```

}
}

i want to use **icon** to show icon in **imageview.** please suggest me how can i get this icon value and how can i user this icon url in imageview.

Thank you in advance.

i am trying this, but still it is creating error:-
this is my code:- but still is creating error:-

JSONArray groups= (JSONArray) jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("groups");

int length= groups.length(); if (length > 0){ for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)

{

```
 JSONObject group= (JSONObject) groups.get(i); JSONArray items =(JSONArray) group.getJSONArray("items");
```

for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++)

{

JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(j);

JSONObject iconobject=(JSONObject) item.getJSONObject("categories");/**/this is creating error that JSON.typeMismatch**

venue.icon=iconobject.getString("icon");

}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    // get into the 'groups' array
    JSONObject jData = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray jGroupsArray = jData.getJSONArray("groups");
    // get into the 'items' array
    jData = jArray.getJSONObject(2);
    JSONArray jItemsArray = jData.getJSONArray("items");
    // get into the 'categories' array
    jData = jArray.getJSONObject(4);
    JSONArray jCategoriesArray = jData.getJSONArray("categories");
    // get into the 'icon' value as String and use it as you please
    jData = jArray.getJSONObject(4);
    String iconURL = jData.getString("icon");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Error parsing data", e);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @micha's post holds an excellent explanation. After you get the iconURL String, simply follow his instructions to update the ImageView

Answer (score 2):

The class [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) can help you:

```
String data = ... // your json data
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```

You can access nodes in your structure with help of `getJSONObject(String)` and `getJSONArray(String)`.

For example:

```
JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray groups = response.getJSONArray("groups");
JSONObject firstGroup = groups.getJSONObject(0);
// and so on
```

When you got your node that contains your icon value you can use the `getString(String)` method to get the icon url:

```
JSONObject firstCategory = categories.getJSONObject(0);
String iconUrl = firstCategory.getString("icon");
```

After you got the url you have to download the image before you can use it. How to download an image from an url is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

When you downloaded the image you can update the imageview:

```
Bitmap image = loadBitmap(iconUrl); // how to implement loadBitmap is shown in the link above
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);
iv.setImageBitamp(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the JSON documentation: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html. It's really simple.

In your case, you would have to read the JSON string to a JSON object, then parse "response" as a JSONObject, "groups" as a JSONArray inside "response", iterate through the JSONObjects contained in the "groups" array, parse "Items" as a JSONArray inside your JSONObject, and son on...

You should be able to get to the URL in no time.